# jquery comparing string with .val(); non expected result

Tags: jquery, string

In my page i have multiple buttons (input type=button) with class ="btnDisabled", every button's value is True or False.

why this code returns always false:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

             $(".btnDisabled").each(function(f,el) {

                 console.log($(this).val() == "False");


             });


         });
```

`typeof ($(this).val())` returns string

Comment: value of a button is always a string.  Is the value "False" or "false", as that has to be exact too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using $.trim()

```
$.trim($(this).val())=="False"
```

can you paste your html?

Answer (score 0):

Just try with:

```
$(this).is(':checked')
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking an example,

```
 <input type="button" class="btnDisabled" value="True" />
 <input type="button" class="btnDisabled" value="False" />
```

In JS :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".btnDisabled").each(function(f,el) {
        console.log($(this).val() == "False"); 
   });
 });
```

Here in console we can see "false" for *true button* and "true" for *false button* which is correct. Please refer [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Wy5Xn/) if still if you not able to resolve this, Paste your complete code in you post.

Comment: Great...  Good luck :-)